# Is the continuous image of a complete metric space complete?

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space and $f:X\longrightarrow X$ be a continuous mapping. Then is it true that $f(X)$ is complete?

I can't seem to get the result in the affirmative unless $d(x,y)\leq d(f(x),f(y))$.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: $f:\Bbb R\rightarrow (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, $f(x)=\tan^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: It is true if $X$ is compact. (Or if $f(X)$ is closed)

Comment: thanks. so, $f(X)$ need not be complete unless we assume more conditions.

Comment: Completeness is preserved under **isometry**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unless we assume some more conditions on $X$ or $f$.